# How to print message to stdout from GNU ld script?

Tags: linker, embedded, ld

I have quite large `ld` link script for embedded platform which is low on RAM and ROM. I want to know how much memory is left available after I have relocated all the code. Actually, I want to print out the value
of location counter `.` to stdout.
How can I do it? Is there some magic command like `print(.)`?

Comment: `ASSERT(0,"Hello there.");` will print a message and exit.  You can use it to assert when the  free room has reach some limit.  Replace '0' with an expression that is enough room.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the [manual](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Scripts.html#Scripts). There are no such commands - there cannot be.

Linker "scripts" are actually more like configuration/descriptor files. They are not "executed" like a script. There is also not a single `.` (how could be for different memory areas?).

You can, however, output a *map* which might exactly be what you need. Try option `-M`. If you have set up the memory regions in the linker script correctly, the linker will warn if some memory area overflows, which is actually what you want for automatic builds.

---

**Update:** You could grep/filter the map file if you want to insist seeing the section sizes on each build.

Comment: But I want to know how much space do I have for the code I will write in the future. However, you're right that there is no such command to print message in ld script, so I will mark your answer as correct.

Comment: @RostakaGmfun: Read the last paragraph again, I edited slightly. There is a way !

Comment: Great! That was a thing I actually needed! Thanks

Comment: They are clearly executed like scripts. `.` is a variable that is updated as the script is "executed". I don't know why you think this would be impossible.

Comment: @Timmmm Just because there is a variable does not imply they are executable files. As much as makefiles are not scripts (although those can even contain snippets of code).

Comment: I didn't say they are executable files. I've read the `lld` source code. It clearly reads the commands and then assigns values to symbols sequentially, "executing" the script if you will. I think you are under the impression that only traditional code can be executed.

Comment: @Timmmm: What is "traditional code"? BASIC source code? BCPL? machine code? Or something like bash script? The latter is a typical scripting language and executed as such (you seem to to think only machine code can be executed - that's not true, the CPU is just an interpreter for byte-code implemented in hardware. Said that: ld control files are not executed in the way one expects for a script. As little as e.g. VHDL is a script (or program) or a Makefile. I'm well aware how a linker (and specifically ld) works. Sure you could call a dove "duck", but that would not make it quack.

Answer (score 4):

Another solution might be to add the following command to the linker:

`-Xlinker --print-memory-usage`

This gives me the following output:

`Memory region         Used Size  Region Size  %age Used
    m_interrupts:         576 B        576 B    100.00%
          m_text:       22988 B      32192 B     71.41%
          m_data:       26552 B        32 KB     81.03%`

Answer (score 3):

I have a post-link step in my projects that dumps the size of stuff so I can see how close I'm getting. Just add something along the lines of:

```
arm-none-eabi-size binary_image.axf
```

That will get you output like:

```
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
 204808     704   23188  228700   37d5c Foo.axf
```

On my cortex-m3 chip, this would be text+data = flash usage, data+bss = ram usage. dec/hex are useless values.

And as Olaf says, use a map file for more specific memory consumption. I have this added to my link step:

```
-Xlinker -Map=Foo.map
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't print the value of a symbol while the script is being executed, but you can create a symbol and the look it up afterwards with `nm`. Like this:

```
value_of_dot = .;
```

Then

```
nm my_file.elf | grep value_of_dot
```

Edit: If you really want it printed to `stdout` you would have to modify the linker. E.g. for `lld`, add `printf`s in `LinkerScript.cpp` in `LinkerScript::assignSymbol()`.

For your particular use-case of checking how much memory is used, it is probably better to use `size`, as escrafford suggested, or `objdump -section-headers`.

Comment: This is in fact even worse than simply checking the map file and it does not what OP asks for (which is clearly impossible).

Comment: It does do what OP asks for if you put it at the end of your script after all the sections (assuming they are in order).

Comment: Using `size` is clearly better for his application though. But people coming to this question from Google might not want to do exactly the same thing.

Comment: No, it does not do what OP apparently wants: output this information to stdout by the linker. Which is exactly what I wrote in my answer: not possible. Plus it is practically not relevant for embedded development. What one wants here is to check if the code/data fits into a **memory region**. That's what the linker automatically checks as I wrote in my answer. And that's what OP **needs**.

Comment: Sure but I came to this question because I wanted to print a symbol value for a different reason, so answering the question he asked is still useful *to other people*. Please remove your downvote. This answer clearly works.

Comment: Additionally, I have inserted `printf()` statements into `lld` and it is possible to print symbol values as they are assigned. The linker doesn't support it but it's not because of anything fundamental.

Comment: 1) You should not assume a downvote is from the same user who left a comment. That could be assumed offending. Otherwise I could assume the DV on my answer was your's. 2) Please point me at the sectrion in the ld manual which describes the `printf` statement? I seem to not be able to find this or anything similar (including other statements).

Comment: It was me. And the `printf` statement isn't in `lld`. I meant that you can add it, and then it does print the value of `.` as it is executing the script, thus disproving your weird idea that it is fundamentally impossible.